# Opening file doesn't open it, it just open the app (eg. for PDF, Preview app opens, but doesn't open the clicked PDF)

Tags: finder

I have an M1 Macbook with Ventura 13.3.1 (22E261), and for some reason double-clicking the files in Finder stopped opening them.

What happens is that the app that should open the file opens (e.g. Preview for PDFs, IINA for movies), but then it doesn't open that file inside the app.

So, I then have to hit Cmd+O, and navigate to the file I just wanted to open in the file dialog.

Any place that I could check to fix this?

Comment: Didn’t' you adjust your double click speed in Settings (to Fastest)?

Comment: "Resolved Issues
Fixes a regression in macOS Ventura 13.3 where a security check causes bookmark resolution to fail when the path contains Unicode characters stored with composed normalization. As an example, this prevented files in Finder from opening when double-clicked. (107550080)" - does that sound right? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-13_4-release-notes

Comment: @Redarm Yes it does! Those were files with some non-ascii characters (like diacritics) in name. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[Redarm](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/49869/redarm) hits the problem in the comments, thanks!

It is a bug in macOS 13.3 and filenames with diacritics or language specific characters. Hopefully, it will have been fixed when macOS 13.4 gets released.

From https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-13_4-release-notes:

> Resolved Issues
>
> Fixes a regression in macOS Ventura 13.3 where a security check causes bookmark resolution to fail when the path contains Unicode characters stored with composed normalization. As an example, this prevented files in Finder from opening when double-clicked. (107550080)