# Can't open PDFs after update

Tags: macos, pdf

After updating to macOS 11.7.6 (and the short-lived version before that) I can't open most of my PDFs through the finder or with the `open` command. When I double click the file, the requested application (preview/skim) opens but no document is displayed. However, if I quit and restart the application and use the `file`->`open` menu, the document can be displayed.

There were no problems before the update. How can I troubleshoot this? How can it be fixed?

**Update 1:**
When I try to open a PDF, the console gives these kinds of error messages:

```
error   containermanagerd   failed to read /Library/Preferences/Logging/com.apple.diagnosticd.filter.plist: [1: Operation not permitted]
error   containermanagerd   failed to read /Library/Preferences/Logging/com.apple.diagnosticd.filter.plist: [1: Operation not permitted]
error   kernel  Sandbox: ContextStoreAgen(435) deny(1) mach-lookup com.apple.ocspd
error   containermanagerd   failed to read /Library/Preferences/Logging/com.apple.diagnosticd.filter.plist: [1: Operation not permitted]
error   containermanagerd   failed to read /Library/Preferences/Logging/com.apple.diagnosticd.filter.plist: [1: Operation not permitted]
error   containermanagerd   [0] command=0, client=<<~~~>, u=<0/0/~~/2/0>, uid=0, pid=378, sandboxed=0, platform=1>, error=21 (CONTAINER_NOT_FOUND)
...
error   accountsd   "Cannot check access to a private account type: (null)"
error   containermanagerd   [0] command=0, client=<<~~~>, u=<0/0/~~/2/0>, uid=0, pid=378, sandboxed=0, platform=1>, error=21 (CONTAINER_NOT_FOUND)
error   containermanagerd   [0] command=0, client=<<~~~>, u=<0/0/~~/2/0>, uid=0, pid=378, sandboxed=0, platform=1>, error=21 (CONTAINER_NOT_FOUND)
...
error   Skim    MTLIOAccelDevice bad MetalPluginClassName property (null)
error   Skim    +[MTLIOAccelDevice registerDevices]: Zero Metal services found
```

**Update 2&3:**

- Creating a new account and downloading a file works.
- Downloading the same file to a different folder on my old account works.
- Downloading and overwriting the same file to the old folder on my old account results in a file that can't be opened.
- `~/Documents` works. In fact, all subfolders down to `~/Documents/work/articles/2023` works, but `~/Documents/work/articles/2023/DÄ` does not work.

Comment: Since most of us don't have 11.7.6 available, could you try creating a new user account and confirming what behavior you see?

Comment: if it limited to a specific folder: which folder is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the same as [Opening file doesn't open it, it just open the app (eg. for PDF, Preview app opens, but doesn't open the clicked PDF)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458494/opening-file-doesnt-open-it-it-just-open-the-app-eg-for-pdf-preview-app-ope). Removing diacritics from the directory name solved the issue.

This [question](https://superuser.com/q/1490652/320813) and [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1490663/320813) that discuss diacritics in file names on macOS led me to a solution. Directories created in the terminal cause problems, but directories created (or renamed) in the Finder are ok.