# Did 13.4 change handling of symlinks?

Tags: finder, command-line, symlink

Some scripts that have been working well for months failed miserably today.

I am not completely certain what's going on; perhaps someone else can confirm or refute what I think I've found:

Formerly, using `open` or double-click on a symlink would get the contents of the target, and `cp` or **File→Save as…** would create a new copy of the actual file.

Today, it seems that `cp` and **File→Save as…** are making new symlinks.  The problem for me is that my scripts depended on moving the actual file into "automatically add to Music".  Now I am getting symlinks there to where the file no longer exists and Music can't import a symlink with no target!

Anyone determine whether my analysis is correct or if wrong explain what is really going on?

The only change between the last successful run and today is the update from macOS_13.3.1_22E772610a to macOS_13.4_22F66.

For what it's worth, 13.4 did fix a [serious bug](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458494/opening-file-doesnt-open-it-it-just-open-the-app-eg-for-pdf-preview-app-ope) that also caused me grief.

Now, the total "gory details" of these scripts, few would want to read, but here's a brief version of what happened in the last successful run:

There are eight "albums" in the Music library.  Seven are different language versions of a couple dozen files of spoken audio.  One "Today's Reading" is the latest file of each album.  In a "Books" directory are symlinks to all the files for the different languages and a text file for each.  In a "Today" directory are symlinks to the seven latest files.

The first script opens the most recent files via the seven symlinks in Today/*, creates seven new (empty) textfiles, and opens seven webpages where the new material will be found.

Next step is manual: copy and paste the text from the web into the text files and download the corresponding audio.  Save and close the text files.  One by one, open the downloaded audio and use copy/paste to replace the audio in the files opened.  Save and close (which is direct to the actual file, not the symlink).

Then another script uses [eyeD3](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to add the text as "lyrics" to the appropriate file, and to update metadata (title, album) for each.  It then copies them to the auto-add directory for Music.app to import them.  Then it changes album/title back to "Today/Language", deletes (empty) the "Today's Reading" album, and copies them again for import to that album.  After a ten-second sleep to ensure that the imports have completed, it deletes the symlinks in Today and recreates them, and adds the new symlinks in Books.

This is what worked well for months, until the [bug previously mentioned](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458494/opening-file-doesnt-open-it-it-just-open-the-app-eg-for-pdf-preview-app-ope).

There was no practical workaround for the bug, and if there had been, changing the scripts would have been proctalgia, so I didn't do the process for a while and **did not** change the scripts.

The 13.4 update appeared to fix that bug, so I ran the scripts again today.  Afterward, the expected new files were **not** in the eight albums and symlinks to the deleted Today files were in the auto-import directory.

So that's why it **seemed like** `cp (symlink) ((auto-import)` had changed.  But maybe something else caused the same result.

I manually rebuilt the original conditions (TM drives not connected) and did the process again.  Same result.

Comment: Can you add the specific steps required for somebody else to reproduce the issue (e.g. by listening the specific Terminal commands).

Comment: No mention to that in [macOS 13.4 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-13_4-release-notes). Nor in https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT213758

Comment: The last change to `cp` was over [8 months ago](https://github.com/apple-open-source/macos/tree/master/file_cmds/cp) and it seems to be superficial version changes.  I can’t see how `cp` and *Save As…* are “creating” symlinks.  That’s just outside their scope.  Please provide some steps to recreate as @nohillside requested.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to be in release notes, because (if it's true), a change of that sort would clearly be a mistake.

Comment: The point here is that the source code for `cp` did not change. And thanks for the details, but what probably would help more is to have clear steps (e.g. list of shell commands) which others can follow to to reproduce the problem on their own system.

Comment: Look, we don't question the effect you see, but we might have some doubt about the potential cause for this. It could be a totally unrelated change in 13.4 which triggers a bug in your scripts which wasn't an issue before, it could be a new bug introduced with 13.4, it could be something else. But without a way to reproduce it it's hard to come up with ideas.

Answer (score 1):

`cp` sees through symlinks to the actual file.

From the man page for /bin/cp

> Symbolic links are always followed unless the -R flag is set

What an application might do is up to the application.

I tested with `TextMate`, and it offered the symlink name for SaveAs, but saved a real file, not a symlink.  With `COTEditor`, it offered the real file name (not the symlink name) for SaveAs, when I changed it, it saved a real file.  `BBEdit` did the same.

Comment: Yeah, there was no change on this during the 13.4 update.

Comment: How does this answer the question, and what exactly has changed with 13.4?

Comment: It's quite possible that my interpretation of the symptoms is incorrect, hence the question.  However, it is quite obvious that an UNCHANGED script is now getting different results.  This is a partial answer in that Marc tested the two features that seem to not be working as designed on my system.